# fread() doesn't add null terminator [C], can't add one because I have a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure, string-formatting, null-terminated

Line 37, I am trying to print the data in my buffer pointer. But I have a pointer (gdhFileProp->buffer) to a pointer (char* buffer). Since I am using fread(), It doesn't add the \0 when reading the file contents. And since it's a pointer to a pointer, I can't add the \0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// Struct to hold the properties of our file
typedef struct {

    int size;
    char* name;
    char* buffer;

} FILEPROP;

FILEPROP* gdhFileProp;

// Function to parse file
int parseFile(char name[]){

    // set name
    gdhFileProp = malloc(sizeof(FILEPROP));
    gdhFileProp->name = name;

    // load file
    FILE* gdhFilePointer;
    gdhFilePointer = fopen("test.txt", "rb+");

    // get file size
    fseek(gdhFilePointer, 0, SEEK_END);
    gdhFileProp->size = ftell(gdhFilePointer);

    //get data and put it into the buffer
    fseek(gdhFilePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&gdhFileProp->buffer, 1, gdhFileProp->size, gdhFilePointer);
    //Print data
    printf("File properties:\nSize: %d bytes\nName: %s \nData: %s\n", gdhFileProp->size, gdhFileProp->name, &gdhFileProp->buffer);

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char name[] = "test.txt";
    parseFile(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior: you never allocate space for `buffer` at all.  You should do that, then you can add a null terminator if you want.  Or try simply use `fwrite(buffer, 1, size_read, stdout);`.

Comment: I took out the malloc() function, and replaced the "->"s with "."s. Works now. Thanks.

Comment: So you still never call `malloc()` and assign the result to `buffer`?  If that's true then your program is still broken.

Comment: I allocated memory for the char *. That's it.